# fullCalendar- how to unselect a selected date

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm implementing a fullcalendar in a project using which users can select future dates.
Is there a way to unselect the selected days?
I tried giving `$("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");` but it didn't work.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/932ynzsc/)

```
var today = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: today,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month'
  },
  defaultView: 'month',
  events: [],
  selectable: true,
  select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    if (moment().diff(start, 'days') > 0) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
      // or display some sort of alert
      return false;
    }

    var date = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
      start: start,
      end: end,
      rendering: 'background',
      block: true,
    }, ]);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");


  },
  selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return !event.block;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi John, did you find a solution to this as I am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
function eventSource(){
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
      start: start,
      end: end,
      rendering: 'background',
      block: true,
    }, ]);
}
var today = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: today,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month'
  },
  defaultView: 'month',
  events: [],
  selectable: true,
  select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    if (moment().diff(start, 'days') > 0) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
      // or display some sort of alert
      return false;
    }
        eventSource();
    var date = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
  },
  selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return !event.block;
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry! This is not the expected solution. I mentioned 'users can select future dates'. Users can select multiple dates. And when I removed addEventSource as you mentioned, I cannot select even a single day. It just became clicking on dates and not selecting. @Saurav Dangol

Comment: @AllenWalker, I have edited the answer.take a look and let me know. Also, remove the second  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect"); to undo the deselection.

Comment: Sorry! This does not work as expected. Using this code, multiple dates cannot be selected. even after deselecting a selected date, it cannot be selected again. @SauravDangol

Comment: @SajeevC your issue is due to the addEventSource in select callback. I suggest you place that code in separate function and try calling that function from your select callback. I tried in your fiddle and it works. Also,I have edited the code. Let me know.